# Firebase data query from two table

Tags: php, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I am newbie in firebase. I did some study and from my study I learnt how to get json data through GET method . I used that url in postman/curl with condition and get my result from one table.(chat_room) Now I want to fetch result using that table id from another table(chat_room_message)

From chat_room_message I just want to get last message where chat_room_id=room_id from previous table(chat_room)

Currently I am using two request to get chat room id and message from another table

```
//get chat room id
$chatRoom = $this->Firebase->controll(null, 'GET', 'chat_room.json?orderBy="tech_guar"&equalTo="' . $userConcat . '"');

$lastChatMessage = '';
$chat_room_id = '';

if (!empty($chatRoom)) {
    $chat_room_id = array_keys($chatRoom)[0];
    //last message from chat history 
    $lastChatMessage = $this->Firebase->controll(null, 'GET', 'chat_room_messages.json?orderBy="chat_room_id"&equalTo="' . $chat_room_id . '"&limitToLast=1');
}
```

Now I just need to decrease post request to firebase. I just want chat room id and last message in one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to SQL's `JOIN` construct in Firebase. You will have to read the entities from both locations separately.

What you *can* do is set up an *additional* data structure in your database for this use-case. So that would be a `latest_message_tech_guard` or something like that.

This means that you store more data, and need to update that data on each write. But the advantage is that reading the information you need for this use-case is trivial. This type of trade-off of write-speed vs read-speed is very common when you use a NoSQL database.

For a good introductions see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and showing me right way. Now I can understand what I have to do.